# StackExchange, 3Sixty and BackOffice

Tags: discussion, exacttarget

Please could someone clarify what is the plan for the [3Sixty](https://3sixty.exacttarget.com/) site? Should we be posting questions to 3Sixty or to [StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exacttarget)? I'm unsure where the best place is to be asking questions and what the future roadmap is for 3Sixty?

On the topic of 3Sixty, while I find this a useful resource, I find case management in BackOffice quite frustrating and primitive. The three main issues are:

1. You cannot add a subject line
2. You cannot apply formatting to your case (for example markdown format for code, etc)
3. You can only upload one file and it can't be an XML file(?!) or zip file

I do hope there are plans to address these core problems, or even better, migrate BackOffice to a more suitable case management system.

Comment: I don't know about 3Sixty.  You can definitely post exact target questions on the Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: [3Sixty](https://3sixty.exacttarget.com) is ExactTarget's online community with user forums and more. It's like a duplicate of StackExchange. It would be great if someone from ExactTarget could clarify if 3Sixty will be discontinued.

Comment: Hey Eliot, going to close this as it doesn't fit the main site, but can you post it on Meta? That's for Q&A about the site itself, and you can find it in the help menu in the top bar :)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest definitely posting any and all AMPscripting and API questions here.  It's best suited for it, and the community will benefit directly from the Q/A. In regards to a direct plan of 3Sixty - I am completely unaware, however I share your opinions.

As always, if you need support, you should be able to email help@exacttarget.com and create a support case.

Comment: I have forwarded your comments to the managers of BackOffice as well.  Hoping it will bring some positive changes for you.